# Google Earth Engine: eq filter not taking values in list

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to filter a raster in GEE with multiple values. I input a list of values and map over the function to apply the filter. Here is the GEE code to loop over a list of numbers and filter the raster (DEM) for values equal to the numbers in the list.

```
var aec = function(n){
  var ii = ee.Image(n)    // casting the number to image before filtering but didn't work
  var DEM141 = DEM.eq(ii)

  var DEM141Count = DEM141.reduceRegion({
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 30,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
  })
  return DEM141Count
}

var elevs = ee.List.sequence(100,150,1);
var areas = elevs.map(aec)
print(areas)
```

I keep getting this error:
`Image.lte, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected: Image<unknown bands>. Actual: Float.`

The GEE code link is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e55360bc82695f930d64ee70a415dc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to define n as a imageConstant with a projection:

```
Map.addLayer(DEM, {min: 100, max: 300}, 'DEM')

var ElevHist = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  region: ROI,
  image: DEM,
  scale: 30,

})

print(ElevHist)

print(DEM.projection())

// var lte = ee.Image(DEM).lte(ii)

var aec = function(n){
  var ii = ee.Image.constant(n)//.reproject(DEM.projection())
  var DEM141 = ee.Image(DEM).lte(ii)

  var DEM141Count = ee.Number(DEM141.reduceRegion({
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 30,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
  }).values().get(0))
  return DEM141Count
}

// print(DEM141Count.get('elevation'))

var elevs = ee.List.sequence(140,150,1);
var areas = elevs.map(aec)
print(areas)
```